# MathJax node vs MathJax runtime processor output font and scaling issue

Tags: node.js, iframe, mathjax

When using MathJax library on DOM directly [inside an iFrame], math gets rendered with correct font-size and scaling relative to surrounding text.

But when using mathjax_node it scales up the equation.

I'am using following code to do the conversion on server side. Which returns an SVG. Then I just replace the MML code present inside an html page with returned SVG.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node");

mjAPI.config({
MathJax: {
    SVG: {
        scale: 100,
        font: "MyriadPro-Regular"
    },
    // MatchWebFonts: {
    //     matchFor: {
    //         "HTML-CSS": false,
    //         NativeMML: false,
    //         SVG: true
    //     },
    //     fontCheckDelay: 2000,
    //     fontCheckTimeout: 30 * 1000
    // }
    }
    });
mjAPI.start();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested- 
    With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


router.route('/processMath')

.post(function (req, res) {

    var _obj = req.body.math;
    var _font = req.body.font;
    var _processed = {};

    fs.readFile('mathRepo.json', 'utf-8', function (err, buf) {
        var orignalSet = JSON.parse(buf);

        Object.keys(_obj).forEach(key => {
            if (Object.keys(orignalSet).indexOf(_obj[key]) !== -1) {

                var _origMml = _obj[key].replace(/<math/g, "<math class='tex2jax_ignore' ");

                var _container = `<span class="MathJax_SVG" style="display:inline-block;font-size: ` + _font + `;position:relative;">
                    `+ orignalSet[_obj[key]] + `
                    <span style="display:none;">
                    `+ _origMml + `
                    </span>
                </span>`;

                _processed[key] = _container;
            } else {
                if (_obj[key].indexOf('<math') !== -1) {
                    mjAPI.typeset({
                        math: _obj[key],
                        format: "MathML", // or "inline-TeX", "MathML"
                        svg: true,
                        css: true,
                        speakText: true,
                        useFontCache: false,
                        useGlobalCache: false,
                    }, function (data) {
                        if (!data.errors) {
                            orignalSet[_obj[key]] = data.svg;
                            console.log(data)
                            fs.writeFileSync('mathRepo.json', JSON.stringify(orignalSet), function (err, data) {
                                if (err) console.log(err);
                                console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
                            });

                            var _origMml = _obj[key].replace(/<math/g, "<math class='tex2jax_ignore' ");

                            var _container = `<span class="MathJax_SVG" style="display:inline-block;font-size: ` + _font + `;position:relative;">
                                `+ data.svg + `
                                <span style="display:none;">
                                `+ _origMml + `
                                </span>
                            </span>`;

                            _processed[key] = _container;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        res.json(_processed);
    });
});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
```

While using MathJax lib it produces following o/p.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYzT6.png)

While using Mathjax node it produces,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk7sR.png)

I am just replacing the MML tags present inside an iFrame with the SVG received from MathJax node. I have to use iFrame since it is an epub.
It scales up and messes the surrounding text. Am I missing out something?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the output that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question with o/p images.

Comment: Images are not enough to answer this as it is very likely the iframe markup that's the problem. An example should ideally be a rich snippet or link to a live sample. (I'm curious why you need an iframe in an epub file though.)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I guess there is some misunderstanding, There isn't any iFrame inside an epub file, but the epub loads inside an iFrame since I'am using a readium reader.   I guess it generated svg in the original scale that of epub files, but readium scales the epub files according to the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Generally,  mathjax-node's SVG output inside an epub file loaded into Readium works fine; the problem is probably in the details that only a sample can provide.

Comment: Have you tried passing different values to the `ex` property of the data sent to `mjAPI.typeset()`?  That says what the ex-height of the surrounding font is, and you may need to adjust that to match your situation.  Also, does the MathML that you are parsing include any `mathsize` or other attributes with absolute (rather than font-relative) units?  E.g., `mathsize="12px"`.  Finally, I note that the font is different in the two images.  Note that `"MyriadPro-Regular"` is not a valid font for MathJax, so that may also be the source of the problem (I think this is probably the real issue).

Comment: @DavideCervone setting ex property actually worked. Now I'm figuring out how can I adjust the ex value according to the font size. <math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\" display=\"inline\"><mrow><mfrac><mn style=\"font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;font-size:25px;vertical-align:-0.2em;\">1</mn><mn style=\"font-family: MyriadPro-Regular;font-size:25px;vertical-align:0.2em;\">4</mn></mfrac></mrow></math> .  This is one of the math I'm retrieving from the epub.  I had to set the ex property to "8" to get the desired o/p.

Comment: Using a font other than one of MathJax's built in fonts will produce poor results in MathJax, particularly mathjax-node.  This is because MathJax doesn't have any of the bounding-box information for the characters in the font.  In the browser, MathJax can at least measure with width, but in mathajx-node even that is not possible, so it will guess the sizes, and that can lead to poor quality results.  It would be better to use something like `scriptlevel=0` rather than `style="font-size:25px"` if you want larger sizes.  Also, mathjax will not take the `vertical-align` into account.

Comment: @DavidCervone I understood. But, there is nothing I can do about the epubs. I'm not allowed to modify the epub pages. Also there are many pages where the MATH is in different font-sizes. I am struggling to set the "ex" property for each of the math received.   BTW thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, sorry you have to deal with the MathML as is.  The ex-size should be the ex-height (in pixels) of the font surrounding the math.  That is what tells mathjax-node how to interpret the `25px` in your styles.  So if you know the font that is surrounding the math and you know its ex-height, and the font-size in use, you should be able to determine the agh ex size to pass to MathJax.  Is the surrounding font relatively consistent in your setup?

Comment: Also, how about filtering the MathML somewhere within your own code?  Like removing the `font-family` or `font-size` specifications.  You don't have to modify the pages, only modify the MathML sent to you from the pages.

Comment: Thanks @DavideCervone. The issue is resolved. As you said, I have removed font-size from MML and used that value to calculate "ex". It worked. :)